# PHP echo vs return JSON response

Tags: json, curl, php-curl

I have a json response of a curl request

```
function getValues() {
$ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $endpoint);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'PUT');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $params);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
        'Content-Type: application/json',
        'Authorization: Bearer ' . $token, 'Content-Length: ' . strlen($params))
    );
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
  return $result; //json response
}
```

For return statement, response is like below with additional quotes

```
"{\"result\":\"success\",\"entry\":\"22\",\"confirm\":\"yes\"}"
```

If the result is echoed,

```
     function getValues() {
 //..snip..
          $result = curl_exec($ch); //json response
          echo $result;
        }
```

json response is

```
{
"result":"success",
"entry":"22",
"confirm":"yes"
}
```

Why the same response is different for `return` and `echo`. Is it appropriate to use echo for a method return.

Comment: This cannot be answered without knowing a lot more about the surrounding code. Echo and Return are two COMPLETELY different things that are not (and should not ever be) interchangeable.

Comment: @Erik added additional code

Comment: how did you know the content of $result in case of return?

Comment: @Yazan I can able to view the content of $result in rest client because this  method returns data for api request

Comment: great, that was my point, involving a 3rd party app or a debugger, who -i think- is responsible for the extra wrapping double quotes, which means they are not really exist, but they are like added on a View level by the rest-client or a debugger, they are not really exist in the variable itself (just my guess) :)

Comment: @Yazan, I think so, double quotes added in SOAPUI and postman rest client but advanced rest client showing without quotes. Its bugging me for couple of days on how to overcome this

Comment: yup it may cause serious pain when you keep digging :), here is a good advice, try to implement this, `if(startsWith(getValues(),'"')){echo "yup return adds extra quouets!";}` this is just to check the value, i know php does not have startsWith() but you can google it alot of samples out there, just to be sure ;)

Comment: @Yazan. Thank you for your answers. One more thing is curl command line request is also sending the output with quotes. Any idea

Comment: i am not sure but -my guess- is 90% no it's not supposed to do that. and it's not doing that.